# Android, Xamarin: Open Dialog from Viewpager Fragment inside of surrounding activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, dialog

I've got a bit of a problem here.
Basically, I have an activity. In the centre of the activity, I inflate a Viewpager fragment with some buttons inside of it. So I have two classes. Now, When the user clicks on the button inside the viewpager, I need to open a custom dialog. I couldn't find a way to implement the custom dialog in within my viewpager class, so I implemented it in within my activity. It does work here when I open the dialog from any button in the activity EXCEPT for the ones that come from the viewpager. Since this is a bit complicated, here an image I drew nicely in the paint: 
[image]

So, I decided to leave the dialog inside the activity and just open it up via the viewpager. This looked like this:

Fragment:

```
        button1.Click += delegate
        {
            var xy = new Activity_Categories();
            xy.click();
        };
```

The activity (Activity_Categories):

```
  public void click()
        {
            ShowDialog(0);
        }

    protected override Dialog OnCreateDialog(int id)
    {

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.btn_bookoflifeMainMenu)
            .SetTitle("test")
            .SetPositiveButton("ok", this)
            .SetNegativeButton("no", this)
            .SetItems(choices, this)
            .Create();


        return base.OnCreateDialog(id);
    }

    public void OnClick(IDialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, which.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();

    }
```

So, what I tried is to open the method "click" from the viewpager that is then opening the dialog. But I get this error:

Unhandled Exception:

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the context "this". But even when I defined a Context context, and in Oncreate went: context = this; . I got the same error.

So the two questions:
How could I open up the dialog from the viewpager fragment? OR
Why am I getting this error?

If you know a better way of doing it, I'd be more than happy to hear! :)

THANK YOU!

Comment: By `Activity_Categories`, is it a `Activity`? If it is, please don't use `new` to create activity. The activity instance always created by system.

Comment: Why don't you just use an activity reference to use those methods